# Searching for a story about a war being prevented by a contaminant found in a town's water supply

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

I'm looking for a short story that I would have read in the late 1980s (possibly early 1990s), about a man who finds a town's water supply is contaminated, but then tries to use this to stop an impending war, because the contaminant has a pacifying effect.  In the long run, everyone becomes ill.  Does anyone know this one?  I don't remember the character names, apologies in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the short story **"The End of the Whole Mess"** by Stephen King.  It first appeared in the October 1986 issue of *Omni*, and was republished in 1993 in his short story collection *Nightmares and Dreamscapes*. A television adaptation was made in 2006.

[image][image]

The story is about a prodigy named Bobby, but narrated by Howard, his older brother, in the form of journal entries.  We learn that Bobby was hired to perform a statistical analysis of crime rates for the government when he discovers that the town of La Plata, Texas has no crime whatsoever.  He visits the town and finds that a chemical in the water supply is responsible for eliminating all of their aggression.  He isolates it and produces a concentrated form of it.

On the eve of nuclear war, Bobby and Howard use an erupting volcano in Borneo to distribute the chemical throughout the atmosphere, causing tensions to drop worldwide and the war to be averted.

But Bobby had made a serious mistake:

> They distributed the chemical before they understood its long term effects — something Bobby could have seen if he had examined the elderly in La Plata.  They all suffer from a neurodegenerative disease that slowly destroys their memories and cognition.  As the story finishes, Howard's writing — which was immaculate to begin with — becomes error prone and starts to make less sense, implying that he is now suffering from the neurodegenerative disease.

Comment: Reminds me of Edmund Cooper's 1971 novel [*Kronk,*](http://www.amazon.com/Kronk-Edmund-Cooper-ebook/dp/B00GU332XI/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) which has a venereal disease that inhibits aggression.

Comment: @JoeL. -- Tha is for the *Kronk* reference, but it's definitely "End of the Whole Mess", the details are coming back to me now and it's exactly the story I was thinking of.  But I never thought the author would be Stephen King, though!  I'm pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @Praxis -- Thanks. I didn't think I would get a response, never mind one so quick. And like I said to Joe, I'm very surprised Stephen King is the author!

Comment: Now I am forming a theory - this chemical is the root cause of the conditions that led that humanity to leave Earth-That-Was, and head to deep space......thousands of years later, it was rediscovered,  isolated and researched by Alliance scientists.....